# Trying to flip a triangle in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC

        mov ecx, 6 
L1:
        call Proc1
        call CRLF
        loop L1

        exit
main ENDP

proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov  al, 'A'
L2:     call WriteChar
        inc al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP

END main
```

The output of my code is

```
ABCDEF
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A
```

In a triangle form going down but I need to flip it to where it is

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDEF
```

Edit:

Trying to mirror the right triangle.

```
A            A
AB          BA
ABC        CBA
ABCD      DCBA
ABCDE    EDCBA
ABCDEF  FEDCBA
```

Comment: Let's see, if `ecx=6` you want to print 1 char, if `ecx=2` you want to print 2 chars, if `ecx=1` you want to print 6 chars. If only there was a simple mathematical operation that does that. Or, you could just count up instead of down :)

Comment: You have two *nested* loops using `ecx` as the counter register, without using the stack. How are you getting that output?

Comment: @owacoder the `USES ecx` does the magic :)

Comment: @Jester - Ahh. I'm used to NASM and GAS, where everything is out in the open. ;-)

Comment: What's your actual problem? Everything else seems in place.

Comment: @RadLexus trying to mirror the triangle

Comment: I just edited my answer to display 2 triangles (mirrored). Check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Jester, counting up is the solution, but only in one loop (I made the little change in your code) :

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC

        mov ecx, 1     ;<=============================
L1:
        call Proc1
        call CRLF
;       loop L1        ;<============================= NO MORE LOOP HERE.
        inc  ecx       ;<============================= CX++.
        cmp  ecx, 6    ;<============================= 
        jbe  L1        ;<============================= IF (CX <= 6) REPEAT.

        exit
main ENDP

proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov  al, 'A'
L2:     call WriteChar
        inc al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP

END main
```

The output now is :

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDEF
```

**Now the mirror** : the idea is to print blank spaces before the letters:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC

        mov ecx, 1     ;<=============================
        mov ebp, 6     ;EBP IS USED AS REVERSE COUNTER FOR BLANK SPACES.

L1:     call spaces    ;</////////////////////////////
        call Proc1
        call CRLF
;       loop L1        ;<============================= NO MORE LOOP HERE.
        inc  ecx       ;<============================= CX++.
        cmp  ecx, 6    ;<============================= 
        jbe  L1        ;<============================= IF (CX <= 6) REPEAT.

        exit
main ENDP

proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov  al, 'A'
L2:     call WriteChar
        inc al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP

spaces PROC              ;</////////////////////////////
        push ebp         ;PRESERVE CURRENT SPACES COUNTER.
        mov  al, ' '     ;SPACE TO PRINT.
L3:     call WriteChar   ;PRINT SPACE.
        dec  ebp         ;DECREASE COUNTER.
        jnz  L3          ;IF COUNTER > 0 REPEAT.
        pop  ebp         ;RESTORE SPACES COUNTER.
        dec  ebp         ;DECREASE ONE SPACE FOR THE NEXT LINE.
        ret              ;</////////////////////////////
spaces ENDP              ;</////////////////////////////

END main
```

**TWO TRIANGLES** : two triangles can be displayed just by calling "Proc1" before and after the spaces, and, very important, the spaces counter, "EBP", must be 12 (for appropiate separation) and, in proc "Spaces", EBP must decrease by 2 :

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC

        mov ecx, 1     ;<=============================
        mov ebp, 12     ;EBP IS USED AS REVERSE COUNTER FOR BLANK SPACES.

L1:     call Proc1     ;LEFT TRIANGLE ! ! !
        call spaces    ;</////////////////////////////
        call Proc1     ;RIGHT TRIANGLE ! ! !
        call CRLF
;       loop L1        ;<============================= NO MORE LOOP HERE.
        inc  ecx       ;<============================= CX++.
        cmp  ecx, 6    ;<============================= 
        jbe  L1        ;<============================= IF (CX <= 6) REPEAT.

        exit
main ENDP

proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov  al, 'A'
L2:     call WriteChar
        inc al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP

spaces PROC              ;</////////////////////////////
        push ebp         ;PRESERVE CURRENT SPACES COUNTER.
        mov  al, ' '     ;SPACE TO PRINT.
L3:     call WriteChar   ;PRINT SPACE.
        dec  ebp         ;DECREASE COUNTER.
        jnz  L3          ;IF COUNTER > 0 REPEAT.
        pop  ebp         ;RESTORE SPACES COUNTER.
        sub  ebp, 2      ;DECREASE 2 SPACES FOR THE NEXT LINE.
        ret              ;</////////////////////////////
spaces ENDP              ;</////////////////////////////

END main
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I am trying to mirror(reverse) the right triangle, would you happen to know how?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, mirror? Do you mean `_____A`, `___AB`, `_ABC`, etc.?

Comment: I mean reverse it A, BA, CBA, DCBA, EDCBA, FEDCBA

Comment: I am trying to put them side by side mirroring each other

Comment: Ok, @Mr.Robot, done! Mirror triangle (I edited my answer, check it out).

Comment: Thank you that is perfect, but how can I do it to output both triangles? I am only outputting the mirrored triangle

Comment: I m trying to make the output look like the output I put up there of the two triangles

Comment: I really can't figure out how to output both triangles

Comment: Anything yet? I still can't figure it out?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, I just edited my answer to display 2 triangles (mirrored). Check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        neg ecx
        add ecx, 7   ; print 7-ecx letters
        mov  al, 'A'
L2:     call WriteChar
        inc al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to mirror the triangle?

Comment: Yes of course. But you could too if you just spent 5 minutes on it. It's not terribly complicated you just need to print some spaces and the letters in the correct order.