# How to output two triangles mirroring each other in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC
        mov ecx, 1
        mov ebp, 6  ;used as reverse counter for blank spaces

L1:         call proc2
        call Proc1

        call CRLF           ;New line
        inc ecx             ;increments ecx
        cmp ecx, 6          ;Limits ecx to n
        jbe L1              ;If (CX <= n) Repeat

        exit
main ENDP

proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov  al, 'A'        ;Stores character in al
L2:         call WriteChar      ;Writes character
        inc al              ;Increments al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP

proc2 PROC  
        push ebp    ;Preserve current spaces counter
        mov al, ' '         ;Space to print
L3:         call WriteChar      ;Print space
        dec ebp             ;Decrease counter
        jnz L3              ;If counter > 0 repeat
        pop ebp             ;Restore spaces counter
        dec ebp      ;Decrease one space for the next line
        ret
proc2 ENDP

END main
```

I am trying to output two triangles like the ones below. I can't seem to get both triangles to mirror each other I am just getting the tringle on the right side. Any help will be very appreciated.

```
A            A
AB          BA
ABC        CBA
ABCD      DCBA
ABCDE    EDCBA
ABCDEF  FEDCBA
```

Comment: The answer to your question : two mirrored triangles (read all the answer, what you need is at the bottom) = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124866/trying-to-flip-a-triangle-in-assembly-language/37125281#37125281

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the above code. proc1 outputs the N first chars from ABCDEF and proc2 outputs 6-N spaces. So what you get should be:

```
     A
    AB
   ABC
  ABCD
 ABCDE
```

Note on the 6th line ebp is 0, so proc 2 will output 2^32 spaces.

You should have something like this in the main loop (note: I assume you want 6 rows, so compare ecx to 7 and initialize ebp to 7) :

```
L1:     call proc1
        mov  ah, al
        call Proc2
        mov  al, ah
        call Proc3
        call CRLF           ;New line
        inc ecx             ;increments ecx
        cmp ecx, 7          ;Limits ecx to n
        jbe L1              ;If (CX <= n) Repeat
```

Where proc3 is:

```
proc3 PROC  USES ecx
        dec al              ;al already contains the last output char+1
L2:     call WriteChar      ;Writes character
        dec al              ;Decrements al
        loop L2
        ret
proc1 ENDP
```

And in proc2 you should output 2 spaces in each iteration, as in:

```
L3:     call WriteChar      ;Print space
        call WriteChar      ;Print space
        dec ebp             ;Decrease counter
        jnz L3              ;If counter > 0 repeat
```

Comment: Thanks, on the second triangle (the one on the right) I am getting unknown characters instead of the letters (a-g)

Comment: You are right. Proc2 uses AL, so it must be preserved. I updated my answer. I opted to use AH as temp storage instead of pushing EAX on the stack (which is slightly slower), but either would work